# Question about almost sure convergence proof

Tags: probability

I am studying about almost sure converge and came across this question

I got the question from this link 
https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter7/7_2_7_almost_sure_convergence.php

[image]

In the case where 2s - 1 > 0. Why do they have to do n > 1/(2s - 1) instead of n > 2(s - 1) which achieves the same result as long as s is a real number.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts. Also, please transcribe the image in a block quote. Also, please embed the link as opposed to pasting it.

Comment: No idea what you're getting at in your question. Why should $n>2(s-1)$ achieve the same result and even if it did why would it be a more natural solution than simply inverting $s >\frac{n+1}{2n}$ to get the required $n$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Not sure why do you say that it is a more natural solution as inverting $s >\frac{n+1}{2n}$

Comment: Inverting that gives the condition $n>\frac{1}{2s-1}$ that guarantees $X_n(s)=0.$ No idea where your $n>2(s-1)$ comes from and don't believe it achieves the same result.